# How to do LogIn Form Animation in WPF?

Tags: wpf, animation

In My project login screen first starts with small size in window corner, then Its with and height grow slowly. At last the screen fit in window center.

How can I do it wpf animation? Is it possible in form?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Trigger for Window using storyboad.

in below code i am animating window from top to center. as this you can change the window Height and width.

```
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
         <BeginStoryboard>
             <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"  From="0" To="200" Duration="0:0:5" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" AutoReverse="False"/>
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"  From="0" To="500" Duration="0:0:5" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" AutoReverse="False"/>
                 <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Top"  From="50" To="200" Duration="0:0:5" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" AutoReverse="False"/>
                             </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>


</Window.Triggers>
```

hope this may helpful.

Comment: You might want to try animating the `Width` and `Height` properties like the question author wanted.

Comment: thank you sir, your animation helped me. but tell me how to resize the window slowly.

Comment: @Sagotharan - i have update my answer, please check.

Comment: @Sagotharan : if this is helpful for you then please mark correct this will useful for another also..